# How to enable button once another button is clicked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

I need to enable the Save Changes , and Cancel Changes button after the Add Another button is clicked. The Save Changes button, and the Cancel Changes button have been disabled on the page load, but for some reason will not enable when the click is passed.

```
   {$().ready(function () {

$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#cancel-default").button().attr('disabled',true).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
$("#add-default").button();
$("#show-default-entry").button();
$("#save-all-defaults").button().attr('disabled', true).addClass('ui-state-disabled');

$(".ko-remove-link").button();

$("#saved-dialog-message").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $("#saved-dialog-message").dialog('close');
        }
      }
});


var AdjustmentsViewModel = function() {

    var self = this;

    // properties
    self.EmployeeId = $("#BaseEmployeeId").val();
    self.Adjustments = ko.observableArray(initialData);

    // methods
    self.add = function (incoming) {
        self.Adjustments.push(incoming);
    };
    self.remove = function (adjustment) {
        self.Adjustments.remove(adjustment);
    };
    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Employee/AddAdjustmentDefaults',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#saved-dialog-message").dialog("open");
            },
            error: function (error) { alert("Error."); },
            always: function () { }

        });
    };
}   

var viewModel = new AdjustmentsViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$("#cancel-default").click(function () {
    $("#show-default-entry").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#entry-row").hide();
});

$("#show-default-entry").click(function () {
    $("#show-default-entry").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#entry-row").show();
});

$("#add-default").button().click(function () {
    var record = {
        "Id": "0",
        "EmployeeId": $("#EmployeeId").val(),
        "AdjustmentTargetTypeId": $("#TargetTypeId option:selected").val(),
        "AdjustmentTargetId": $("#TargetId").val(),
        "AdjustmentTargetTypeDescription": $("#TargetTypeId option:selected").text(),
        "AdjustmentTargetDescription": $("#TargetId option:selected").text(),
        "Amount": $("#Amount").val()
    };
    viewModel.add(record);

    $("#show-default-entry").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#entry-row").hide();
});
});
}
```

Comment: Please write attr enable code of the button ofter success function

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I haven't written any code to turn off the jQuery on click just yet. I want ("#add-default).button () when clicked to change the state of (#save-all-defaults ) and (#cancel-default) to be enabled.

Comment: sorry but after I added that, the button still shows disabled when i click the add-default button

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$("#show-default-entry").attr("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **removeAttr()** instead of **prop()**

```
$('#my_selector').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Use this

```
$("#add-default").button().click(function () {
var record = {
    "Id": "0",
    "EmployeeId": $("#EmployeeId").val(),
    "AdjustmentTargetTypeId": $("#TargetTypeId option:selected").val(),
    "AdjustmentTargetId": $("#TargetId").val(),
    "AdjustmentTargetTypeDescription": $("#TargetTypeId option:selected").text(),
    "AdjustmentTargetDescription": $("#TargetId option:selected").text(),
    "Amount": $("#Amount").val()
};
viewModel.add(record);

$("#show-default-entry").removeAttr('disabled'); //enables button
$("#cancel-default").removeAttr('disabled');   //enables button

$("#entry-row").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I haven't written any code to turn off the jQuery on click just yet. I want ("#add-default).button () when clicked to change the state of (#save-all-defaults ) and (#cancel-default) to be enabled.

Comment: just use above code to enable the buttons in your onclick event. It will remove the disable attribute from the buttons.

Comment: Should I call this at $("#add-default").button().click(function ()

Comment: Hi, after I inserted your code, once the button is clicked it still returned default. it's almost as if the buttons did nothing at all.